# User to user messaging with django-postman

Tags: python, django

I'm new using django-postman and django and I just downloaded a copy of the django-postman package to use with my app. I added `'postman'` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` settings.py of my project and  `url(r'^messages/',include('postman.urls',namespace='postman',app_name='postman')),` in urls.py. However, I'm not sure where to put the downloaded package and integrated with my project. I think I added the app to my Python path with `pip install django-postman==3.6.2`, but when I use `url(r'^messages/',include('postman.urls',namespace='postman',app_name='postman'))` my django program says that there's not an app called 'postman'. How do I include the django-postman app to my project? Also since the app_name='postman' in urls.py is not longer valid for python 3.6 should I just take it out of the statment?

Comment: How do you run you django app? Are you using any virtual environment? Do you install `django-postman` to the same python you are using to run django app?

Comment: I using pycharm IDE to edit django files and I run the app from the command line. I did the pip install django-postman==3.6.2 in the the django app folder

Comment: Are you able to `import postman` in python shell?

Comment: I did put it in urls.py but it doesn't look like is being used. Is there anything else I need to include with import postman?